What is the difference between [ɚ], [ɝ], [ɹ̩], and [ɻ̍]?
So, [ɚ] is a rhotacized schwa/mid central vowel/schwar, [ɝ] is a rhotacized open-mid central unrounded vowel, [ɹ̩] is a syllabic alveolar approximant, and [ɻ̍] is a syllabic retroflex approximant. What's the difference between all 4?

There's not necessarily a difference at all! It's like how there's not necessarily a difference between [j] and [i̯], or [d̥] and [t]. It's entirely possible to make two IPA characters that refer to the same sound with the right diacritics.
If someone uses [ɚ] alongside [ɝ], then the IPA definitions tell us that the second one is a little more open/low, and if someone uses [ɹ̩] alongside [ɻ̍], then the second one is more retroflex. But if any work uses [ɚ] alongside [ɹ̩], I'd expect that work to include an explanation of how exactly they differ, since the IPA symbols themselves don't clearly indicate it.
(Same for any work that uses [d̥] alongside [t], which some do. This sort of redundancy isn't necessarily a flaw in the IPA, but the IPA has some inherent imprecision in it. That's why a good grammar should include a discussion of these things alongside an IPA chart.)

The current IPA definition tells us that, but in reality any work that uses both [ɚ] and [ɝ] does so most likely to distinguish between unstressed and stressed vowels, as that was the distinction made by the IPA definition before 1993.

@Nardog Interesting, I didn't know that! That would make a good answer in its own right. (I don't actually know how to find old versions of IPA definitions.)

@Draconis The History of IPA article has a pretty good overview. According to that, ⟨ɜ⟩ was considered “a variant of ⟨ə⟩” from 1932 until 1993. It doesn’t say anything about them being stress-based variants, though, but then I do find that rather odd, since (as far as I know) stress has never been indicated by the vowel symbols themselves in the IPA proper (as opposed to in its use for specific languages). The same page shows that ˈ and ˌ were adopted in 1925 and haven’t changed since.

See for example IPA (1912: 12): "ə stands for any obscure vowel of neutral quality, like the first of English again. It is convenient to reserve this sign as far as possible for unstressed vowels. In cases where it is found desirable to distinguish two such vowels, the one with higher tongue position may be written ə and the one with lower tongue position ɐ."
